# iPhone XR's screen triggers other devices

Tags: iphone, hardware, speakers, signal

Recently I bought a brand new iPhone XR. When its screen is activated by some application (not necessarily a GSM call or a Wi-Fi thing), it affects other speakers or headphones around it. All of them sounds exact same 4 "buff" like sounds consecutively.  It reminds me of the way old mobile phones affected the speakers around them. Is there anyone knows why it happens and how to prevent it? It annoys me and I really need a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this kind of speaker interference happens when there is a large amount of cellular data transfer. If you keep your phone on WiFi and enable WiFi calling, you may experience it less since WiFi is a lower strength signal than cellular?

I don't know if there is another way to avoid this...

Comment: I don't think it is about the intensity of the cellular data because I didn't experience it before with my iPhone 6.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps because your speakers and headphones are unshielded.

Quote from [this](https://forums.audioholics.com/forums/threads/shielded-speakers-what-exactly-does-that-mean-for-moving.22078/) website:

> Shielding a speaker (actually the driver(s) are shielded) typically
> involves using a second magnet, known as a bucking magnet, on the back
> of the driver magnet. This keeps the magnetic field from creating a
> large stray field that can affect closely placed electronic equipment.
> How well it does this varies from speaker to speaker. There is still a
> stray field, however, it is typically small enough to allow CRT
> monitors or TVs to be placed reasonably close. With the air space
> inside the cabinet providing a buffer zone a CRT can often be placed
> immediately next to the speaker without adverse effect. This applies
> whether the speaker is powered or unpowered.

So, you have two options: Use Airplane mode and use only Wi-fi in your house, or buy shielded speakers/headphones. It's not an Apple's problem; it's inherent in all GSM phones.